# Can't upgrade or downgrade NuGet package

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a ASP.NET Core website, and it relies on 2 class libraries.

They all reference Microsoft.NETCore but the versions have got mixed up somehow and has lead me to receive warnings:

> Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 1.1.0 to 1.0.3

NuGet won't let me change the version of `Microsoft.NetCore.App`:

[image: Cant update package]

If I try to upgrade or downgrade, I get the error

> Following versions are unavailable due to additional constraints in the project or packages.config

How do I solve this error?

My csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>AutomotiveWebPortalCore</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>AutomotiveWebPortalCore</PackageId>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-AutomotiveWebPortalCore-20170223120414</UserSecretsId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*;Views\**\*;Areas\**\Views;appsettings.json;web.config">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExtreme.AspNet.Core" Version="16.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExtreme.AspNet.Data" Version="1.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader" Version="14.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="3.3.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="HubSpot.Tether" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.2.301" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\AutomotiveDAL\AutomotiveDAL.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\AutomotiveDTO\AutomotiveDTO.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Edit:**

Here are the references for my class libraries:

Data Access Layer:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Data Transfer Objects:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you post all dependencies with versons?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Smithy Does your project use `project.json` or `.csproj` to reference packages? Can you post the contents of that file?

Comment: @NateBarbettini I've added the contents of both files that show all package references

Comment: @J.Doe I've added the package references, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @Smithy Let me know if my answer (editing the csproj directly) helps. As a side note, I think your class libraries may not be set up correctly. They should not reference `Microsoft.NETCore.App` themselves. If they do, you should remove it!

Comment: @NateBarbettini Your solution worked and removed my warnings so thank you very much, I have added the CSProj files from my libs, do they seem OK to you? Thanks again :)

Comment: My class libs are also built using core to add them I Added Project -> .NetCore Class Library and the above in the edit is what I have

Comment: @Smithy Your class libraries should target `netstandard1.X`, not `netcoreapp1.0`. Try changing the `TargetFramework` to `netstandard1.3`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Following versions are unavailable due to additional constraints" message seems to occur even in a brand new, empty ASP.NET Core project. I think it's either a bug or a feature of the NuGet GUI. (I'm using the final release version of Visual Studio 2017)

You can work around it by directly editing the .csproj file: right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select **Edit (projectname).csproj**.

You can bump up the version of Microsoft.NETCore.App (and the target framework) in the first PropertyGroup:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>

  <!-- snip -->

  <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>

  <!-- snip -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then, close the file and rebuild the project. I tested this with all the (public) dependencies you mentioned in your question and didn't see any package version conflicts.

Comment: You're a star mate! VS with the dodgy tooling still then!

Comment: I've edited the .csproj directly and this solved the warnings about getting downgraded, I checked my other class libraries and they point to netcoreapp1.0 also. I've edited my answer to show, is this good or bad?

Comment: Is <RuntimeFrameworkVersion> a valid tag in netcore2.0? I ask because Intellisense doesn't know about it.

Comment: @EoRaptor013 It's still valid according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj), but it's not usually required.

Comment: instead of `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>x.y.z</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` which requires to specify the exact version number, you can use `<TargetLatestRuntimePatch> true </TargetLatestRuntimePatch>` see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51404441/2803565

Answer (score 0):

Also check for a file Directory.Build.props.  This can contain references that appear to override the version specified in the csproj file.  There can be multiple versions, living in the root of the solution or each individual project.